# IIS7 create website / application pool / web application pool ( i have the script ) but i want to build in security

Tags: security, web-applications, iis-7, web, powershell-2.0

i'm creating a PS script to deploy my website INSTALL & RAD and do alot of other things .. they all work but i want to build in security .. lets say if the app pool is not created don't create the webapplication RADServices and use the app pool : RADServices...

I hope you get the point.

here is my script with no controle but fully working , i will always fixed parameters since i copy the script to the server i want to launch the action on.

Script that will install RAD and add mgrRAD to local groups

pastebin.com/5TCdzSwU

As you can see there is no security in this script :(

I want to double check if the folder INSTALL is there when i create the website INSTALL.
I want to double check if the folder RAD is there when i create the website RAD
I want to double check if the app pool RADServices is there when i create the webapp pool etc etc

I already tried some things but i can't get it to work.